# Anything like Git's Tig for SVN?

Tags: svn, logging

I need to browse over edits like in Git's Tig but with SVN. I basically need to see just the patches. How can I do that? Any easy visual tool or some commandline option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

1. Subversion's `blame` (TortoiseSVN has a nice graphical viewer for this)
2. The [Timelapse View tool](http://code.google.com/p/svn-time-lapse-view/)

Comment: How can I see the file before the edit let say 141? `svn diff -c 141 file` not working, `svn blame file` not telling the content -- I need timelapse view tool for it? I am on OS X, have to try how it compiles...

Comment: I got the timelapse running but it is not mature code, firing exceptions, and it got hang up when I tried to select a file.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Timelapse was a very nice tool; it probably doesn't handle the new SVN databases. TortoiseSVN's blame would work but not on OS X.

Comment: There is no ready command/flag in the commandline tool "svn" to see the file let say of revision 141 or day something?